# Where is the geo command located on android?

Tags: android, geo

I am trying trying to fix geolocation to android on a rooted device
using

`geo fix 12 77`

response i get is

> geo: permission denied

upon rooting i get

> geo: not found

if i knew where the script was located, I could cd and execute the command

P.S i tried telnet to port 5307 but with no luck

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search indicated to me that the geo fix command is for manually setting a mock location, and probably wouldn't be useful for obtaining a real fix on your location.

Could you please provide a bit more information? What phone and ROM/version are you using? When did this problem start? Have you checked the XDA forums for your device?

Comment: I am trying to set the mock location for my android device via terminal to test my app which does not work well on the emulator.. I am using and Android 2.2.2 Tablet (Viewpad 7)